# Referencing XML file in a referenced project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a utility project that has an "XML" folder with two XML files in it, this project is then referenced by an ASP.net web project. I was wondering do you have to set some sort of build option to place the folder in the BIN of the website, or is there another approach to referencing these two files from the web project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select one of the XML file in the solution explorer, then in the properties list you should see a property called "Copy to Output Directory", set this to "Always Copy".

Do this for both files.
That should then bring the files into the referencing projects bin folder.